# How to fade in element right after fadeout (vanilla/pure javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I have this ajax form that returns a script that controlls the 'sent' animation. however when the fade in starts it stops at .1 opacity. I am not sure what is wrong in the script. Any help would be appreciated.

```
quote_form = document.getElementsByClassName('quote-form')[0];
var timer = setInterval(function () {
  if (!quote_form.style.opacity) {
      quote_form.style.opacity = 1;
  }
  if (quote_form.style.opacity > 0) {
      quote_form.style.opacity -= 0.1;
  } else {
    clearInterval(timer);
      quote_form.innerHTML = '<p>Thank you for answering this graphic design quote questionnaire! You should receive a confirmation email shortly</p>'
      var timer2 = setInterval(function () {
        if (quote_form.style.opacity != 1){
            quote_form.style.opacity += 0.1;
        } else {
            clearInterval(timer2);
        }
      }, 50);
  }
}, 50);
```

no errors display in the console. you can try the code at this page:

https://tester.desertsunstudio.com/el-paso-graphic-design-quote-texas-southwest-united-states-web-developer-graphic-designer-desert-sun-studio

thank y'all very much!

Comment: what if u use css's  ```@keyframes``` to make animation

Comment: @DostonbekOripjonov would that allow me to make a callback function to set the .innerHTML

Comment: no. but, just make div with `display: none` and when user makes action I mean when you want to display your message add class that makes animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is types!

You're comparing string values of opacity to a number, and also trying to concatenate these values:

`"0.1" + 0.1` == `0.10.1` - this will break your interval

You'll need to cast the value of the read opacity value to a float to update it

```
const styles = window.getComputedStyle(quote_form);
const opacity = parseFloat(styles.opacity);
// returns 0.1 not "0.1"
```

Functional demo: http://jsfiddle.net/shannonhochkins/agq81svz/7/

For a simple fade-in and out, I would be using flat css transitions/keyframes and javascript as a trigger but this should help you either way

**Update:**

Very simple animation with css only and a trigger to add the class when we want it to animate:

http://jsfiddle.net/shannonhochkins/agq81svz/21/

Comment: thank you! this has the functionality I was looking for! If I could get a smoother transition using css id really appreciate you pointing me to some documentation or keywords for google. haha sorry i am barely transitioning from jQuery to vanilla JS and im having a time of it:P

Comment: I added a css animation example @sal

Comment: that you very much!